# How to use linux grep command?

Tags: linux, logging, grep

I can only grep and display a particular line of a log file.
What if I want to display the next line together?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: SO is for programming questions. Questions about basic use of Unix tools would be better on unix.SE or SuperUser.com.

Comment: Hi Jared, Your solution worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

cat **filelogname** | grep **keyword**

example : cat /var/log/httpd/error.log |grep Hello

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? And it should be `grep Hello filename`